# url path parameter with % sign

Tags: java, regex, url, parameters, path

I am using `rg.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler`
need to capture the url path

```
URL: video/Id19%2Fabc%3D/title?sub=CDA
```

I have tried the following to capture but this doesn't capture `%` sign.

```
@Path("/video/{Id:.*}/title/")
```

Comment: `%2F` is a `/` encoded

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://regex101.com/r/qYs7gQ/3

```
Regex: video\/Id(?<ID>.*)\/title
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to handle URL encoding request. It is handled on Application server level and in my case, it is apache tomcat. So all I need to do is set

org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true in catalina.properties file.